# Does the sum ${\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}} \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I decide whether ${\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}} \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}$ converges or not?

I was thinking to use the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{n}$ but I became sceptical to whether I can use the expression $\frac{1}{n}$ or not when I made a plot of the expression $a_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}$ together with the expression $\frac{1}{n}$. It seems that $\frac{1}{n}$ becomes larger than $a_n$ above when $n$ grows large

Is this the right thing to do?

Comment: It is highly recommended to show some effort. What have you tried?
Hint - $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+n+\sqrt{n}+1}\le \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}$.

Comment: One thing that works is limit comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n}$. Or prove directly that each term is $\ge \frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: The $n$'th term is bounded below by ${\sqrt n\over 3n\sqrt n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}
  \frac{\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n\sqrt{n}+n}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}
  \frac{n\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}}
  \frac{1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}+\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}}
       {1+\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{n}}}=1
$$
Or note that
$$
\dfrac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1}\ge
\frac{\sqrt{n}}{3n\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{n}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I actually did it like this also, but I became somewhat sceptical because it seems that the expression is larger than $\frac{1}{n}$ when $n$ grows larger when I plot the expression together, does this matter?

Comment: @PhillipA If it grows larger than $1/n$ it diverges. But it's sufficient it grows larger than $1/(3n)$.

Comment: Doesn't the condition $0 \leqq a_{n} \leqq K\cdot b_{n}$ apply for the "limit comparison test" (Sorry for nagging but I just want to make sure that I haven't misunderstood something...)

Comment: @PhillipA The terms are positive; if the limit exists and is finite, either both series converge or both diverge. The criterion you mention is more general and can be applied also if the limit I used doesn't exist; but with the limit it's easier, if applicable.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 2):

For $n \ge 1$,
$$\frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1} \ge \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}+1} = \frac{1}{n+1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \ge \frac{1}{n+2}$$
so your series is divergent by comparison test.